# How to read ports and ip-adresses out of PCAP-File using WinPCAP Api?

Tags: port, ip-address, pcap, winpcap

I am currently trying to read some `PCAP` files using `WinPCAP-API`.
With [this example](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut7.html) I managed to read the data, timestamp and length. But I do not get how to read the source and destination IP-adresses and ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I do not get how to read the source and destination IP-adresses and ports?

By dissecting the raw packet data that WinPcap gives you; libpcap/WinPcap provide no APIs for dissecting raw packet data (because different libpcap/WinPcap applications have different needs - an intrusion detection application such as Snort and a packet analyzer such as tcpdump or Wireshark do different things with the data).

See, for example, [libtins](http://libtins.github.io) as a C++ library for doing packet dissection, or the [libpcap tutorial](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) for an example of how to do the dissecting yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!

Comment: After some changes `sniffex.c` of `libpcap tutorial` was successfully compiled. But I do not get what changes to make to read my pcap-file? I tried `dev = "D:\path\to\udp.pcap"` but that causes the program to crash. I also tried `dev = "port 4321"` to just read my File while it is replayed with `Colasoft-Player`, but I get the same crash (console output):
_Device: port 4321;
Number of packets: 10;
Filter expression: ip;
Couldn't open device port 4321: Error opening adapter: System cannot find device. (20);_

Comment: Those aren't crashes, those are error reports.  [`sniffex.c`](http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c) is *not* a program that reads pcap files, it's a program that captures on whatever devices libpcap supports - which doesn't include network ports such as "port 4321".  You'd have to change it to use `pcap_open_offline()`, rather than `pcap_open_live()`, to make it read capture files.

Comment: Thank you the readed data seems to be correct!
Next project will be to convert and change the data / header and write them back into a pcap file.